# django access foreignkey value on CreateView class

Tags: django, django-views

I have a form that submits data, but before submitting to the database it will take the value from foreign first.

here my `models.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("system:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class EmpLoan(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='emploan')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp.name

class EmpInstallment(models.Model):
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    loan = models.ForeignKey(EmpLoan, related_name='empinstallment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.loan.emp.name
```

`view.py`

```
class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ()
    model = models.Employee

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        data = self.object.EmpLoan.EmpInstallment.object.get(id=1)

        self.object.nik = data
        self.object.save()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

how to access data on `EmpInstallment`?...

iam trying use this `data = self.object.EmpLoan.EmpInstallment.object.get(id=1)`

but it's not working.

iam still learner and very noob on django

Comment: `nik` is declared as a `CharField` and you are trying to set a `ForeignKey` as the value, what exactly are you trying to do within the form save method?

Comment: @rtindru because nik use char & number so i use CharField, but its will unique, nik will different every employee & cannot same.

Comment: Does the response below solve your issue?

Comment: @rtindru got error `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'empinstallment'`

Comment: Ah makes sense; the answer would work for `OneToOneField` but yours is a `ForeignKey` lookup.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? An employee can have multiple loans, and each loan can have multiple installments. When you are saving the employee; and trying to access an installment, which loan and which installment are you interested in accessing?

Comment: @rtindru yes, but this case just sample. I will do with my salary table. my scheme is before post `employee salary` my system check `employee loan` first, if they still have an active loan, my system will calculate and cut the salary and then post to `installments` every month. if sum `installments` equal `loan` my system will change `loan` status. then employe can loan again. I will update my code.

Comment: based on your explanations above, my answer should work now, I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

EmpInstallment -- > ForeignKey to --->  EmpLoan -----> ForeignKey to ---Employee

```
class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
fields = ()
model = models.Employee

def form_valid(self, form):
    employee_instance = form.save(commit=False)
    # try to get the emploan instance
    emploan = employee_instance.emploan.first()
    if emploan:
        empinstallment = emploan.empinstallment.first()
        if empinstallment:
             pass # there you can execute your codes


# there you have access to empinstallment
```

Comment: @Dicky Just wanted to flag that each of these `RelatedObject` accesses can potentially raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist` -> be mindful of that in your code.

Comment: you're right @rtindru, ensure of each of them has the ForeignKey. updated my answer. thanks.

Comment: @Lemayzeur got error `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'empinstallment'` what should I do?...

Comment: Updated my answer @DickyRaambo

Comment: i will check tomorrow, gonna sleep now. anyway, thank you!